# Bad Results: time(NULL) and clock()

Tags: c, macos, time, clock

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <time.h>

int main (void) {

    printf("Clock ticks per second: %d\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    double check = clock();
    int timex = time(NULL);

    for (int x = 0; x <= 500000; x++) {

        printf(".");

    }
    puts("\n");

    printf("Total Time by Clock: %7.7f\n", (clock() - check) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
    printf("Total Time by Time: %d\n", time(NULL) - timex);

    getchar();
}
```

When I execute the above code I get results like:

Total Time by Clock: 0.0108240

Total Time by Time: 12

I would like to have clock() represent a number as close to as possible as time.

The total time presented above was done on a macbook, however, the code works excellent on my laptop (windows).

The CLOCKS_PER_SECOND macro returns 1000 on the PC, 1,000,000 on the MAC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

clock() on windows returns the wall clock time. clock() on *nixes return the CPU time your program has spent, which is not going to be a lot, you're likely blocked when doing I/O here.

Comment: Thanks nos. Is there any work-a-round for mac I can do to implement a wall-clock time to wall-clock time that is strictly C, using standard library usage only?

Comment: Or the more modern `clock_gettime`, which can provide up to nanosecond resolution.

Answer (score 1):

printf() to console makes system call for each functon call, and time spent blocked in console redrawing, etc. do not count for process time.

Make some heavy calculations there.

```
for (long int x = 0; x <= 5000000000; x++) {
    sqrt(2.9999);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that clock() ONLY counts active usage of the process itself? Not tracking, say: a timestamp, from the beginning of the application till one point?

Comment: It's implementation dependent. Some UNIX implementations count as much as waited child processes CPU time, other just calling process CPU time. Anyway, if your process tried to call printf() and was blocked because of xterm input pipe was full - this blocked time definitely will not be counted in clock()... on all systems but Windows: there clock() returns wall-clock time, not CPU usage. Generally, avoid using clock() if possible: there are much better defined calls like times() and getrusage().

Comment: Thanks Blaze, after releasing an app already, I've come to realize that clock(), and NSTimer just aren't as efficient as calling the actual time. :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`time()` returns a `time_t`. When you assign that to an `int` it is possible that you lose information. What happens if you use `time_t` throughout?

```
int main(void) {
    time_t timex = time(0);
    /* ... */
    printf("%d", (int)(time(0) - timex));
}
```

Comment: Use difftime to calculate `time_t` differences.

Comment: I'm not having a problem using time(0), only clock(). Thanks for the help however. time(0) seems to be working just as it should - returning time in seconds since a specified date.